# Ubuntu 14.04 VLC Subtitles - Will not attach (unable to drag/drop or upload while viewing)

Tags: 14.04, vlc, subtitle

I'm new to Ubuntu and a long time user of VLC with the Windows OS. In Windows, I was able to drag and drop the `.sfv` file onto the playing video and the subtitles would be enabled. In Ubuntu I try to drag and drop the .sfv file and it acts as though the .sfv file is a video and stops the actual video from playing. When I try to attach the .sfv file (view - subtitles - select text subtitles) I'm able to see the .sfv file I'd like to attach/open, although once I click open the file doesn't attach itself to the video.

Does anyone know how to help me with this situation? I'm 2 seasons deep into Breaking Bad and attempting to read the body language of the characters during the Spanish parts has gone on way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing SRT and SFV.

**SRT** is a filename extension used for files containing subtitles in [SubRip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.srt#SubRip_text_file_format). To my experience VLC automatically picks these up if you put them in the same directory as the video file.

**SFV** stands for [simple file verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sfv) and is solely used in the warez scene.
Talking about warez is not allowed here as far as I know.

You should open the file with a text editor to verify that it really is a subtitle file format.